# Assistance needed with connecting to and using a UNSPSC web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I've looked on the web and there seems to be 2 available UNSPSC web services:
http://www.restfulwebservices.net/Service.aspx?ID=24

and

http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=74&CATID=2

I've added these service references to a test console app to try and use these services.
Unfortunately, these service providers do not seem to have customer support so I'm hoping maybe someone here can help me out.

For the restful web service, I've tried connecting to the SOAP endpoint but I'm getting an exception saying: "Invalid object name 'dbo.unspsc'. It kinda sounds like a problem on the service side but I can't be sure. Here's my code, maybe someone can see what's wrong with it. The exception is being thrown when I call GetDetailsByClass.

```
ServiceReference1.UNSPSCServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.UNSPSCServiceClient();
client.Open();
ServiceReference1.UNSPSC[] commodities = client.GetDetailsByClass("81112006");
```

For webservicex, I can connect to the web service but I have no idea how to use it. I don't understand how to use the methods provided, such as GetUNSPSCCommodityByClassRequest & Response. How does the request return a Commodity object? How do I perform a search for a UNSPSC code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations.  First, SOAP and REST are two different types of web services, and are accessed two different ways.  SOAP services are accessed via a proxy (which is generated for you when you add a service reference in Visual Studio).  REST services are accessed through an HTTP API, like the [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Neither of the links you posted are web service links, though they do have links to web services.  The first one exposes two endpoints (one for SOAP and one for REST) on a WCF service.  The second one uses a legacy ASMX web service (which is no longer supported by Microsoft).  I would not use the webservicex one unless I had no choice, since it is legacy technology.

As far as the error you're getting, it sounds like there's an issue with the database behind the service, and if that's the case it's definitely on the service side.  The code you posted looks correct, and I tried it myself and got the same error (on the SOAP endpoint).

Intellisense should help you in how to use the various methods (if there is no documentation to be found).  But for the error you encountered, you'd need to talk to the developers of the service.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I'll somehow try to get in contact with their customer support to see if its a problem on their part. And the webservicex code doesn't have any documentation and it does look and feel very old. I'll steer clear from that one for now. Thanks a bunch